# how can i pass the selected value of dropdown list to user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, drop-down-menu

how can i pass the selected value of dropdown list to user control
.aspx

```
<select id="DropDownList2">
     <option value="product1">Police Schemes1</option>
     <option value="product2">Police Schemes2</option> 
     <option value="product3">Police Schemes3</option> 
 </select>
```

.ascx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //string selectedvalue = "";


            }

            }
```

Any assistance or suggestion will be apreciated

Comment: Do you want to add a blank item to the top of dropdown (saying `string selectedvalue = ""`)?

Comment: I hope you use `<asp:DropDownList />` server control. Please, clarify what is code you provided. Is `<select ...>...</select>` a source rendered to browser?

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute runat="server" and get it Like this.

In html put attribute runat="server"

```
 <select id="DropDownList2" runat="server">
     <option value="product1">Police Schemes1</option>
     <option value="product2">Police Schemes2</option> 
     <option value="product3">Police Schemes3</option> 
 </select>
```

In code behind put this

```
string selectedvalue = DropDownList2.Value;
```

Comment: sorry it was Value not SelectedValue

Comment: look at the code in my answer I made the option runat="server" do that it will become accessible then

Comment: both ascx and .aspx page has different code behind , so how can i accessthe aspx dropdownlist in user control , it still comes up with the same erro

Comment: Its seldom when we require ascx control to be accessed in aspx. You may not need this. Can you tell me why you require this.